# Openvas Setup Won't connect to dl.greenbone.net

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, raspbian, penetration-testing, openvas

I'm a beginner here,
I'm using a raspberry pi-4 running raspian OS. I'm trying to run sudo openvas-setup but it just fails to connect to dl.greenbone.net over and over again at least 20 times before finishing with errors. Can anyone tell me why this is? I'll paste code below:

--2021-05-20 19:00:56--  (try: 3)  http://dl.greenbone.net/community-nvt-feed-current.tar.bz2
Connecting to dl.greenbone.net (dl.greenbone.net)|2a01:130:2000:127::d1|:80... failed: No route to host.
Connecting to dl.greenbone.net (dl.greenbone.net)|89.146.224.58|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-05-20 19:03:15--  (try: 4)  http://dl.greenbone.net/community-nvt-feed-current.tar.bz2
Connecting to dl.greenbone.net (dl.greenbone.net)|2a01:130:2000:127::d1|:80... failed: No route to host.
Connecting to dl.greenbone.net (dl.greenbone.net)|89.146.224.58|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Answer (score 0):

the server has been shut down more then a year ago. The Greenbone OpenVAS version you are using a very very outdated and can't be used anymore. Maybe updating raspbian helps. Otherwise you can try building it from source with https://greenbone.github.io/docs/